# Laravel Asset Exists But Returning 404 Not Found

Tags: laravel

I got problem when accessing public asset on Laravel.
I copy and paste an image (app.png) to (app_baru.png) on a same directory (app/public/fe/eduzone/images/).
But the new asset is return 404 when being acessed on web browser, meanwhile the old asset is shown normally.

Here is my file permission:

[image]

Here is my file shown on web browser:
[image]

I've confirm that my storage is pointed to another directory, not to public directory:
[image]

I also have done some php artisan command like:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

But the asset still not snown on browser.

Please help

Comment: Please try `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I did, but still not working.

Comment: The screenshots show images in `/fe/eduzone/images/`.  That's not the directory you describe (`/public/images`).

Comment: Sorry I just want to make shorter description.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is Case Sensitive, try uppercase extention.
"app_baru.PNG"
See your file name extention.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the imagename in the storage (in your case media) folder and not in the public folder.

Comment: Actually there is no more image beside on that directory, as I mention before, the link storage is pointing to another sub directory, not to puplic directory.